# "error" or "wrong"?

Tags: word-choice

For example:

> - What's error in this sentence?
> - What's wrong in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sentence is correct.

'Error' is a noun. It describes something that *is* wrong.

'Wrong' is an adjective, and so is applied to the subject ('this sentence') to describe it.

To write a correct sentence with the same meaning as the second one, while using 'error', you would say something like:

> Where is the error in this sentence?

Comment: Is "What's wrong in this sentence?" grammatical? Shouldn't it be "What's wrong with this sentence?"

Comment: @Tragicomic: [There's a question for that.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45/whats-wrong-in-this-question) (^_^)

Comment: I was concentrating more on the wrong/error part, but I'd say 'with' as well yes.

Comment: You could also say *What's **the** error in this sentence?*

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following one:

> What's wrong **with** this sentence?